# CFSocketSetAddress bind failure: 48 after reopening stream

Tags: ios, swift, streaming

Hello in my iOS Swift application I'm displaying a live stream.

Therefore I've created this function to start the stream, which is called when a specific containerView is loaded:

```
func startStream() {

    let masterViewController = self.parentViewController as? MasterViewController

    let ip = RTPTools().findLocalWifiIp()
    print("local IP: \(ip)")

    let view = masterViewController!.streamView
    view.waiting = true

    masterViewController!.receiver = RTPReceiver(localIp: ip, listenPort: 5000)
    masterViewController!.receiver!.delegate = view
    view.setNeedsDisplay()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MasterViewController.decodingFailed(_:)), name: AVSampleBufferDisplayLayerFailedToDecodeNotification, object: self.view.layer)

    Connector.sharedInstance.runLivePreview()

    masterViewController?.showStreamView()
}
```

I'm calling this method in the viewDidAppear function and setting the notification functions like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(InformationsViewController.restartStream), name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(InformationsViewController.clearStream), name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)

    startStream()
}
```

The clearstream and restartStream functions are looking like this:

```
func clearStream() {
    let masterViewController = self.parentViewController as? MasterViewController
    masterViewController!.receiver = nil

    Connector.sharedInstance.stopLivePreview()
}

func restartStream() {
    let masterViewController = self.parentViewController as? MasterViewController

    let ip = RTPTools().findLocalWifiIp()
    print("local IP: \(ip)")

    let view = masterViewController!.streamView
    view.waiting = true

    masterViewController!.receiver = RTPReceiver(localIp: ip, listenPort: 5000)
    masterViewController!.receiver!.delegate = view
    view.setNeedsDisplay()

    let videoLayer = view.layer as! AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer
    videoLayer.flushAndRemoveImage()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MasterViewController.decodingFailed(_:)), name: AVSampleBufferDisplayLayerFailedToDecodeNotification, object: self.view.layer)

    Connector.sharedInstance.runLivePreview()

    masterViewController?.showStreamView()
}
```

The thing is, that when I click on the home button while the stream is running and then go back to the application everything starts and works fine. But I get the CFSocketSetAddress bind failure: 48 Error, when I switch the view to another view and then switch back to the view where the stream is running.

The RTPReceiver is implemented like this:

```
@implementation RTPReceiver

- (id) initWithLocalIp:(NSString*)ip listenPort:(uint16_t)port {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }
    self.localIp = ip;
    self.listenPort = port;

    //create socket
    CFSocketContext socketContext = {0, (__bridge void*)self, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    CFSocketRef socket = CFSocketCreate(NULL, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP,
                              kCFSocketDataCallBack , MySocketCallback, &socketContext);
    NSAssert(socket, @"Socket creation failed");
    self.socket = socket;
    CFRelease(socket);

    //set address
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_len = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([self.localIp cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
    addr.sin_port = htons(self.listenPort);
    NSData* address = [NSData dataWithBytes:&addr length: sizeof(addr)];

    // HERE IS THE ERROR
    CFSocketError sockErr = CFSocketSetAddress(self.socket, (CFDataRef) address);
    NSAssert(sockErr == kCFSocketSuccess,@"Set socket address failed");

    //add to run loop
    CFRunLoopSourceRef source = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, self.socket, 0);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetMain(), source, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CFRelease(source);
    return self;
}
```

I don't understand why I get this error, while I'm doing the same process to start the stream. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also finding a solution.

Why don't you use below instead of CFSocketSetAddress

```
    if (0 != (err = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)))) {
        NSLog(@"Bind error");
        return false;
    }
```

Because in documents,

> This function binds the socket by calling bind, and if the socket supports it, configures the socket for listening by calling listen with a backlog of 256.

Using **bind** works for me and now I'm also finding a way to use CFSocketSetAddress.